# compare data in the same table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I compare the difference in user's balances between 2 date points from the same table in MySQL?

provided I have a table that records data as follows.

| user_id | balance | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2021-03-31 |
| 2 | 10 | 2021-03-31 |
| 3 | 20 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-04-01 |
| 2 | 8 | 2021-04-01 |
| 3 | 13 | 2021-04-01 |
| 4 | 5 | 2021-04-01 |

> EXPECTED OUTPUT

| user_id | balance_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 17 |
| 4 | 5 |

Comment: Pardon me but I don't understand how the difference for `user_id` 2 is 8 and for `user_id` 3 it is 17. Shouldn't the difference for `user_id` 2 be (10 - 8) and for `user_id` 3 it should be (20 - 13).

Comment: Expected output values looks like absolutely inconsistent...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For version 5.x

```
SELECT user_id, t2.balance - t1.balance difference
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (user_id)
WHERE t1.created_at = '2021-03-31'
  AND t2.created_at = '2021-04-01'
```

On 8+ use window function (`balance - LAG(balance)`).

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select user_id,
       case max(balance) - min(balance)
           when 0 then max(balance)
           else max(balance) - min(balance)
       end as difference
  from t
 group by user_id
```

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ba4e67e82683099bb2d71cb5eaaaa947)

Answer (score 2):

if it is always two specific date you want to compare :

```
select 
  user_id 
  , sum(case when created_at ='2021-04-01' then balance end) 
    - sum(case when created_at ='2021-03-31' then balance end)
from tablename
where created_at IN ('2021-03-31','2021-04-01')
group by user_id
```

this method calls table only once

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Select a.user_id,a.Balance-b.Balance from table1 a 
LEFT JOIN table1 b ON a.user_id=b.user_id GROUP BY a.user_id,a.created_at;
```